# Inverse Laplace transform of a non-negative function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, real-analysis, integral-transforms, laplace-transform

Consider an *entire* function $f$, which is real for real arguments and satisfies $f(s)\geq 0$ for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, assume this function is a Laplace transform,
$$
f(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}d\mu(t).
$$
For example,
$$
f(s)=e^{-e^{-s}}=\sum_{t=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^t}{t!}e^{-st}\geq 0.
$$

In my case, $d\mu$ is always supported at discrete points, but results for nicer $d\mu$ are also helpful.

Given this information, what necessary (and, ideally, sufficient) conditions can one derive on $d\mu$?

This can be compared to a similar problem, where one assumes $\mathrm{Re} \,f(s)\geq 0$ for $\mathrm{Re}\,s\geq 0$, which seem to result in the requirement that $d\mu(t)+d\mu(-t)$ is non-negative-definite distribution. (See e.g. [this](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/0113071) paper by Konig and Zemanian)